# A question on mysql command

Tags: server, mysql, email, postfix, mail

I want to config postfix. I followed [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassasin).

On the first step I saw this mysql command:

```
mysql > GRANT SELECT ON servermail.* TO 'usermail'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'mailpassword';
```

also the description for that is :

> First we need to create a new user, specific for mail authentication,
>   and we are going to give SELECT permission.

Finally my question is. Is that create an user with name **usermail** on my Ubuntu?

Comment: This question does not belong here, since it is not ubuntu specific.

Comment: @Pabi from http://askubuntu.com/tour, _Ask about...

Using and administering Ubuntu, including official Ubuntu derivatives.
Running third-party applications on Ubuntu.
Development on Ubuntu.
Services provided by Ubuntu
Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered_

Comment: This is about running 3rd-party applications on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have created a **database named** `servermail`, now the guide says that you must create a **user named** `usermail` with **password** `mailpassword`.

The names can change to whatever you like, just keep consistent naming.

The **usermail** user must be created inside MySQL shell. He is not related to system's users.

If you follow the guide and type:

```
GRANT SELECT ON servermail.* TO 'usermail'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY 'mailpassword';
```

in `mysql>` prompt, **you will** create a user named `usermail` that will have **select** privileges on `servermail` database which is located at local host (127.0.0.1) and the user's password will be `mailpassword`.

It is a copy & paste procedure just **remember to set a secure password!**